# tomcat and jar parallel execution in a maven build

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jar

I have a maven build which runs my application with the tomcat7-maven-plugin on a run profile.
I would like to run a jar (for example with maven-exec-plugin) in parallel with the tomcat execution. This jar is a ldap service I use for local development.

So far I've been abled to run this jar in a separate maven execution (other pom) :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>run</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>x.y.z.ldap.LdapServerRunner</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>localhost</argument>
                    <argument>50000</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/resources/ldap-dev.ldif</argument>
                </arguments>
                <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>j</artifactId>
            <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
            <version>x.x.x-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

If I add this in the same pom of the maven-dependency-plugin, maven wait for the main to end before starting the tomcat execution.
I would like to know if it is possible run my jar (x.y.z.ldap.LdapServerRunner) at the samed time of my local tomcat execution.

Comment: Have you tried [Parallel builds in Maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)?

Comment: Nope, I'll have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my tactic :
Instead of absolutely trying to make a separate jar execution to work in parallel (and handle all the related problems), I've also made my jar a war (in a specific maven profile) :

- I've created a simple class implementing **javax.servlet.ServletContextListener** where I've written my server start and stop in **contextInitialized** and **contextDestroyed** methods.
- I've put a simple web.xml in my project (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) with :

  ```
   <listener>
       <listener-class>x.y.z.EmbeddedLdapListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
  ```
- I've included  my ldap war with the application war :

  ```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
         <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <webapps>
            <webapp>
              <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
              <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <type>war</type>
              <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
              <contextPath>/myapp</contextPath>
         </webapp>
         <webapp>
           <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
           <artifactId>myldapembedded</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <type>war</type>
           <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
           <contextPath>/ldap</contextPath>
        </webapp>
        ...
  ```

PS : for the properties part (port, server, etc.), I've used System properties.

1. You can define them in the tomcat7-maven-plugin :

   ```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
            <configuration>
               <systemProperties>
               <myproperty>myvalue</myproperty>
   ```
2. And then use it in your Listerner :

   ```
          System.getProperty("myproperty", mydefaultValue)
   ```